# Chart.js Auto Fit Failing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm running into an issue where a bar chart won't update the y- axis scale when a dataset is deselected from the legend. I'm using the 'suggestedMax' option under yAxes to add some padding to the top of the tallest bar. If I don't, the scale will just top out at the tallest bar(3500). I read the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html?h=suggestedMax) and it states that suggestedMax should still auto fit the data but that's not what I'm experiencing.

Docs state the following:

> The suggestedMax and suggestedMin settings only change the data values that are used to scale the axis. These are useful for extending the range of the axis while maintaining the auto fit behaviour.

Here's the chart:

```
var ctx1 = document.getElementById("myBarChart1")
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2/17','2/18','2/19','2/20','2/21','2/22'],
    datasets: [
    {
      label: "Bar 1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
      data: [2500,1000,1500,3500,2000,500]
    },
    {
      label: "Bar 2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.6)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      data: [50,0,100,1250,500,0]
    },
    {
      label: "Bar 3",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,51,0.6)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,255,51,0.6)",
      data: [0,0,150,250,550,200]
    },
    {
      label: "Bar 4",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,102,0.6)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,255,102,1)",
      data: [2450,1000,1250,2000,100,0]
    },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          color: "white"
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 6,
          fontColor: "white"
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 15,
          fontColor: "white",
          padding: 10,
          suggestedMax: 4000
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          color: "white"
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: "white",
      }
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Uses Bootstrap 4 -->
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">Test Status Chart</div>
  <div class="card-body" style="background: #212529">
    <canvas id="myBarChart1" width="170%" height="40%"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

To recreate what I'm getting click 'Bar 1' in the legend, the scale should remain at max 4000 vs scaling down to the next highest number(2450).

When I remove the suggestMax option is works perfectly, minus the fact the scale tops out at 3500. I get the same issue when using the max option as well.

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working solution.

Define a function getMax() which takes in a chart and returns the maximum value of all the **visible** datasets.

```
var getMax = function(chart) {
    datasets = chart.data.datasets;
    max = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) {
        dataset=datasets[i]
        if(chart.data.datasets[i].hidden) {
            continue;
        }
        dataset.data.forEach(function(d) {
            if(typeof(d)=="number" && d>max) {
                max = d
            }
        })
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then to options.legend, add an onClick function to call it and reset the y-axis suggestedMax to that max value plus 100 (you can tune this however you want):

```
  options: {
    <...>
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        fontColor: "white",
      },
      onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        di=legendItem.datasetIndex
        myBarChart.data.datasets[di].hidden = !myBarChart.data.datasets[di].hidden;
        myBarChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax=getMax(myBarChart)+100;
        myBarChart.update()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So I attempted to implement this but the reference to myBarChart in the onClick event is throwing an undefined error.

Comment: You are using that name in `var myBarChart = new Chart()` right?

Comment: Yes I am, I just double checked that.

Comment: I have my implementation in pastebin. Just save as index.html and open in the browser. What's the difference between what I have and what you have? https://pastebin.com/VGeKkwbB

Comment: Just compared them, nothing is different. The only thing that's different is that I'm loading my data via an API. Outside of that, the chart is identical.

Comment: Very strange. If you open up the html page in a browser, then open up the console, and just type `myBarChart.data.datasets[0].hidden` does it give you `true/false` or the reference error?

Comment: Tried the console, got the reference error. Very strange indeed, the example you provided works when I test it but for some reason it's not working on my side.

Comment: I just realized that my getMax() function called `myBarChart` instead of just `chart` so I edited that in. Anyway, in your console, can you try to find your chart variable? `for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}`

Comment: I was able to fix it on my side. I just updated the getMax function to use the chart parameter vs 'myBarChart'. - Ha, we both saw the same thing. It's working great now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like we both caught that at the same time :)